# JavaScript does not work when I view my page in my phone browser

Tags: jquery, github, github-pages

I have recently deployed a page using GitHub and when I check it on my laptop it works as it is intended to but the strange thing is that the jQuery part in my script file does not work at all when I check it in my android phone browser. Any suggestions what I did wrong? I thought I should give it more time to be uploaded properly but it seems that that's not the case. All the files including the html, CSS and script file are in the same folder. Here is the GitHub link: 
https://mohammad-pishdar.github.io/Work-Day-Scheduler/

Comment: Debug the android browser from your PC to see javascript errors, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17179570/1572595

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did as Zeb Rawnsley has suggested and upon debugging the android browser I have found out that the problem was that the local storage of my phone's browser already contained data from a previous work that I have done and deployed to my github so when my new app wanted to check the local storage it couldn't recognise that object in there... anyways, just clearing the local storage on my phone browser solved this problem